# Multiple Strings in on label MIPS

Tags: string, mips

How do I change between different strings in a label if I have:

```
.data
test_words:
    .asciiz "Cat"
    .asciiz "Tree"
    .asciiz "Dog"
    .asciiz "Lamp"
    .asciiz "See"
    .asciiz "Mole"
    .asciiz "Mice"
    .asciiz "Goldfish"
    .asciiz "Ship"
.text
```

Thank you in advance and sorry if my question is stupid im new to MIPS :).

Comment: Put labels before each string, then create another table with all the string addresses. Another alternative could be to pad all the strings to be the same length; then you could calculate the correct address without needing another table, but at the cost of wasting some space.

Comment: Hey Polak, you could have asked questions regarding our homework assignment in our course's Forum and participating in the question sessions which we provided more frequently during homework time. Also the answer to this question is not relevant for the solution which is the reason why individual strings are not labeled. The iteration over these words is given in the homework template already.